# Catch a exception with interface.

Tags: php, exception, interface, try-catch, catch-block

I have a question about the exception handling in PHP.

I have a lot of exception those means the same: Couldn't found something. All those exception implements the interface (*not class*) `NotFoundException`.
So to my question: It's possible to check if the exception implement the interface at the catch-block.
I know i could change the NotFoundException-interface to a class but some exceptions extended already an other exception. (Example: `CategoryNotFoundException` extends `CategoryException` and implements `NotFoundException`).

Why should I need this interface?
When an page is showing and some exception which implements the interface will throw an Error404 should shown.
Example:

```
$userPage = $_GET["page"];
try{
    showPage($userPage);
} catch (){ //How to catch the `NotFoundException` interface?
    showPage("Error404");
} catch (Exception $e){
    showPage("Error500"); //Something is wrong...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply specify the exception class (or interface) you're trying to catch:

```
try {
    showPage($userPage);
} catch (NotFoundException $e) {
    showPage("Error404");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    showPage("Error500");
}
```